# how to modify the autocorrelation default plot style and write the output of a acorr function to a dat/txt file?

Tags: python, matplotlib, correlation

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.mlab as mlab`
```

`mu = np.loadtxt('my_data/corr.txt')`

```
d = mu[:,2]
y=[]
tot=0
min=999
for i in d:
   y.append(float(i))
tot=tot+float(i)
if (min>float(i)):
    min=float(i)

av=tot/len(y)
z=[]
m=[]
for i in y:
z.append(i-av)
m.append(i-min)
plt.acorr(z,usevlines=True,maxlags=None,normed=True)
plt.show()
```

WIth this code I have the output showing a bar chart.

Now,
1) How do I change this plot style to give just the trend line? I cant modify the line properties by any means.
2) How do I write this output data to a dat or txt file?

Comment: Try `usevlines=False` and setting the parameters you want in `acorr`

Comment: nope! It doesnt work!

Comment: works for me: `acorr(x, color='r', linestyle='-', marker=None, usevlines=False
`

Comment: in my answer i also adressed your second question

Comment: it works as well..Thanks a lot. But why do you suggest  not to connect the points?

Comment: because they are discrete points. As they are integers there is nothing in between. Connecting them with a straight line would probably lead to wrong assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

this should be a working minimal example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import normal

data = normal(0, 1, 1000)

# return values are lags, correlation vector and the drawn line
lags, corr, line, rest = plt.acorr(data, marker=None, linestyle='-', color='red', usevlines=False)
plt.show()
np.savetxt("correlations.txt", np.transpose((lags, corr)), header='Lags\tCorrelation')
```

[image]

But i would recommand not to connect the points.